# Delete Docker from Docker?

Tags: docker, controls, containers, monitoring

Is it possible to control (list/start/stop/delete) docker containers from docker container running on the same machine?

The idea/intent is to have docker container which monitors/controls neighbours.

Both low/high level details would be useful.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the easiest way is to mount the docker socket from the host inside the docker container e.g:

`$ docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker debian /bin/bash
root@dcd3b64945ed:/#  docker ps -q
dcd3b64945ed
3178d5269041
e59d5e37e0f6`

Answer (score 1):

Mounting the docker socket is the easiest however its unsecure as gives the root access to everyone who has access to the docker.sock

Id suggest using the Docker Remote API to do the list/start/stop/etc with a program which hides the docker remote ( in your case local ) daemon .

Ref: https://docs.docker.com/articles/basics/

Comment: How is giving access to the Docker API any different to giving access to the sock? It's the same thing, just a different interface.

Comment: Thats why you hide it within another /'program'/ and only give out an interface to just do the start/stop/listing and not do anything else.

Comment: Given that starting a container is pretty much the most dangerous operation, that would achieve practically nothing. I'd actually go as far to say your suggestion is less secure, as now you have an API exposed to the network.